# In the equation: $z = (\sqrt3+i)^n$ determine the values of $n$ for which $z$ is a real number.

Tags: complex-numbers

Question : In the equation: $z = (\sqrt3+i)^n$ determine the values of $n$ for which $z$ is a real number.

Working:

$z = (\sqrt3+i)^n $

$z^\frac1n = (\sqrt3+i)$

$z^\frac1n = (2cis(\frac\pi6 + 2k\pi))$

I'm not quite if my working is correct, its just similar to what we have done in class I don't really know how to approach the question after this.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Instead of worrying about such things as "$z^{\frac1n}$", why not compute $(\sqrt3+i)^n$?

Comment: Why not calculate $z^2$ and $z^3$ and ... stop right there, and look for a good hunch.

Comment: @dxiv as in n=2? or n = 0.5

Comment: $n=0$ seems nice

Comment: @YuriyS that was my answer, but I thought there would be more to it

Comment: @Conal $\;(\sqrt{3}+i)^3=8i\,$.

Comment: @dxiv yes I got that too, not sure what it means though

Comment: @Conal It means that $z^6 = -64 \in \mathbb{R}$, and therefore $z^{6n} = \left(-64\right)^n \in \mathbb{R}$ for all integer $n$.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Conal, you've got great answers already, but I would also suggest you brush up on the vector interpretation of complex numbers, where multiplication corresponds to both stretching and rotation. Then all this will become clear to you

Comment: @YuriyS Will definitely look it up, this is just an extension question I was given in class we'd never looked at before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have
$$
z=2\left(\frac {\sqrt3}2+\frac i2\right)=2 (\cos\frac\pi6+i\sin\frac\pi6).
$$
Thus $$z^n=2^n (\cos\frac {n\pi}6+i\sin\frac {n\pi}6). $$ For the imaginary part to be zero, we need $\sin n\pi/6=0$. The sine is zero precisely on the integer multiples of  $\pi $. So $z^n $ will be real when  $n $ is a multiple of $ 6$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Glad I could help!  :)